# How can I configure a gzip compressed response in ASP.NET Web Api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, gzip, iis-express, http-compression

I have found numerous articles and blog posts which go into detail of the various ways this can be accomplished. Some look involved with custom coding, and are (right at this moment) not what I am wanting (I want a configuration solution). Some of these posts (SO included) share how to do this through configuration over custom coding, but to no success on my end. Here is my attempt so far. Have I overlooked anything? Is my `Web.config` to blame, or is there something else I must specify on my request?

### Additional Details

- I am running **IIS Express 8** (product version: 8.5.9748.0) on my
  localhost
- Windows 8.1
- I am making requests with Fiddler - but the same response occurs with ajax calls (AngularJS)

### Fiddler Get Headers

> User-Agent: Fiddler 
>   Host: localhost:5293 
>   Accept: application/json; charset=utf-8, application/json
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip

### JS Request (AngularJS)

```
$http.get('localhost:5293/api/Whatever', {
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json; charset=utf-8, application/json',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip'
    }
});
```

### Problem

My response is always

> application/json; charset=utf-8

### Efforts

- I have enabled **Dynamic Content Compression** and **Static Content Compression** on Windows features under IIS (Turn Windows features on or off)
- Reset **Windows Process Activation Service**
- Run following commands, and verified the results as such

  ```
  appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/httpCompression /+"dynamicTypes.[mimeType='application/json',enabled='True']" /commit:apphost

  appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/httpCompression /+"dynamicTypes.[mimeType='application/json; charset=utf-8',enabled='True']" /commit:apphost
  ```

Verify Command:

```
appcmd.exe list config -section:system.webServer/httpCompression
```

Verify Response:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
    <staticTypes>
      <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="application/atom+xml" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="application/xaml+xml" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
    </staticTypes>
    <dynamicTypes>
      <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
      <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="application/json; charset=utf-8" enabled="true" />
    </dynamicTypes>
    <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" />
  </httpCompression>
</system.webServer>
```

I have placed this exact configuration in my `Web.config` file under the `<system.webServer>` node, and still no luck...

### Web Api Controller Method

```
public JsonResult Get()
{
    return new JsonResult
    {
        Data = "foo",
        ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
    };
}
```

Comment: Looks more like MVC rather then Web API.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, don't dictate the format. Let content negotiation do its job. And compression will start working too:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    return Ok("foo")
}
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer. I just tried this and composed a GET fiddler request. Still no compression and same content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8

Comment: @salniro: You may need to use [this](https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebAPIContrib/blob/master/src/WebApiContrib/Content/CompressedContent.cs). Also see [that](https://github.com/azzlack/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.MessageHandlers.Compression).

Comment: Thanks for the resources. I too came across the `CompressedContent` method. I rather not though, at this moment. Is there not a straightforward way to configure this?